# Decision Tree producing 0.5 value at split for binary variables

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree

I have a lot of categorical variables which I converted to dummy variable by one hot encoding for each of the features and plotted a decision tree in R. I am not able to understand the output. Can someone please help me to explain how a split a a node can have 0.5 as value when the variable has only 0 or 1. Code and decision tree below

```
mtree <- rpart(Converted~., data = training, method="class",
               control = rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 7, maxdepth = 5,
                                       usesurrogate = 2, xval =10 ))

rpart.plot(mtree, # middle graph
           type=4,
           extra=101, 
           box.palette="GnBu",
           branch.lty=3, 
           shadow.col="gray", 
           nn=TRUE,cex = 1
)
```

#### [Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQurz.png)Tree

Example : For the variable Month June which is one hot encoded how do I explain Month.June >=0.5

Comment: If `Month.June` is dummy encoded with `1` for June and `0` otherwise, then when it is June the dummy encoding (1) will exceed the 0.5 threshold, and when it is not June it will not. What are you confused by?

Comment: 0.5 is half way between 0 and 1.  `Month.June >=0.5` is identical to `Month.June ==1` but since your variables are numeric rather than factors, rpart is using the midpoint of the existing values.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor....I was not sure how to interpret the 0.5 value. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @G5W...Thanks for the explanation